# Why `wc -m` counts 1 character more?

Tags: command-line, bash, wc

Why `wc -m` counts one character (symbol) more from `here-string` (<<<)

Here is example:

```
$ TEST_STR="askubuntu"
$ echo "$TEST_STR"
askubuntu
$ wc -m <<<"$TEST_STR"
10
```

It is saying 10, but actually there is only 9 symbols.

The same problem appears for `wc -c`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because Bash **Here strings** add trailing newline character.

Here is proof:

```
$ TEST_STR="askubuntu"
$ echo "$TEST_STR"
askubuntu
$ od -c <<<"$TEST_STR"
0000000   a   s   k   u   b   u   n   t   u  \n
0000012
```

---

Also, there is a few nice answers that explains why newline character should be there:

1. [Why here string add newline character?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20157/why-does-a-bash-here-string-add-a-trailing-newline-char)
2. [Why new line character should be there?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18743/whats-the-point-in-adding-a-new-line-to-the-end-of-a-file/18789#18789)